# How get to Orgrimmar from 1st lvl Garrison?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to stop getting XP and need to get to Orgrimmar to [Slahtz](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=35364/slahtz) for this.
How do I do it from 1st lvl Garrison?

I know that you can get there from Ashran. And people says that there is a portal to Ashran from west Mage building. There is Mage building at lvl3 Garrison, but I can't find neither it or a portal at lvl1 Garrson.

P.S. And I can't do any quests, because then I would lvlup to 91, which will mess up everything.
P.P.S. Asking another player to help is not an option either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "expected" way to return to Orgrimmar (or Stormwind!) from your Garrison, or anywhere on Draenor, really, is via Ashran. Khadgar warns you it might be awhile before you can return when you charge through the dark portal with him!

Level 1 and 2 Garrisons will provide access via a flightpath to Ashran, while a Level 3 Garrison will provide a direct portal. To the best of my knoweldge, this flightpath is unlocked as part of a level 91 quest. Alternatively, you may visit someone *else*'s Level 3 Garrison and use *it's* portal to Ashran.

In addition, there are always the "class-based" methods of returning to Azeroth -- Mage / Death Knight / Druid / Monk self-teleportation, Mage Portal, and Warlock Summon, and "item-based" methods -- Hearthstone / Atiesh / Dalaran Ring / Guild Cloak teleportation, etc. As a level 90, you may even be able to use Dungeon Meeting Stones to be summoned to Mists of Pandaria areas (though randomly queuing through LFG won't do the trick).

Comment: You need to do the first quests in the garrison to get to Ashran.

Comment: While you're correct that this does not apply to the OP's situation, I think it not unlikely that other users might stumble onto this question but without the OP's self-imposed restrictions. I deemed it worthwhile to provide a "general solution" for such visitors.

Comment: Please add the stone option, which is the most reliable, since it should be set outside of Draenor at the very beginning. Also DK has a teleport to Eastern Kingdoms. And r wank has mentioned few items in his answer, which is also an option.

Answer (score 4):

Given your constraints, as to what you can/can't do, your best bet is to pick up the cloak from your guild vendor to teleport you to Orgrimmar before you get to the garrison. If that is no longer an option the only way to get back is to get summoned or quest on. You can ask a mage for a portal, but you stated you can't ask other people for help. so you're sorta stuck.

Another option is to get the epic Dalaran teleport ring when you're lvling, and use that to teleport to Dalaran, from there you can take a portal to Orgrimmar.

Those are the 2 items I can think off that will let you teleport to Ogrimmar, without the help of other people.

Comment: So you are sure, that if I am already in a Garrison, then I either must ask for help or do the quest?

Comment: IF you cant quest to unlock actual ashran, theres no way to get off draenor, unless you ask another person to teleport/summon you. Where did you set your hearthstone, because you get the garrison hearthstone so i dont see why you would set it there?

Comment: You could try open a ticket stating that your stuck, maybe a nice enough GM will help you to get back to Ogrimmar

Comment: Ok. Sad and fine. Fortunately, I had hearthstone at west kingdoms (which I stupidly forgot about :) ). I accepted your answer, but I would like to see hearthstone option here.

Comment: west kingdoms? if you have the heartstone set somewhere not draenor, then you can get back to ogrimar and set your HS there

Comment: *Eastern Kingdoms

Comment: If you are in Eastern Kingdoms there is 2 Zeplins that take you directly to Ogrimar from there.

Kalimdor ↔ Eastern Kingdoms

The Iron Eagle: Orgrimmar, Durotar ↔ Grom'gol Base Camp, Stranglethorn Vale

The Thundercaller: Orgrimmar, Durotar ↔ Undercity, Tirisfal Glades

taken from http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Zeppelin

Comment: There are another option. You can find a group like "herb traider", such a groups accept you automatically, then you switch to another garrison and find an ashran portal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a creative way, you can always ask a warlock in Orgrimmar to summon you.

I'm making the assumption here that you already have access to trade chat in a first level garrison. I'm not sure anymore, I didn't pay much attention before I upgraded to the next level.
If you do, you can use trade chat to find someone, if no one in your guild can.

You can also party up with a mage, have them visit you in your garrison and make a portal.

Why prevent leveling up? Just curious :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want disturb other players. Preventing leveling is the only way to try lvl90 raids and heroic dungeons.

Comment: The only way I know is Ashran then. Unless you never set your Hearthstone to Draenor but I'm guessing you did since you're asking this question. The portal is in one of the houses. IIRC, walk away from the flight master spot after landing, and the house is on your left hand side. Going from memory here.

Comment: so how to get to ashran?

Comment: I got a quest from Gazlowe to go there (when on the quest, you can ask the flight master to take you). I think that was still on my first level garrison, so unless you're pushing against the XP barrier, that's the way to do it.

Comment: @flater the quest to go to Ashran unlocks at 91. so that's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

In the unlikely event anyone finds themself in this situation again, asking for help can be easy, so don't rule it out. Group Finder (green eye lower right) > Premade Groups > Custom > Start a Group. Title your group something like "need mage in garrison; quick" List the group and wait. Be sure to add anyone who tries to join. When a mage joins, ask for a portal to Org. Before you click the portal, if you can spare it, open a trade window with the mage and tip a few gold. If you can't spare it, be sure to /w or /p "thank you SOOOOO much!" once you are in Org.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative way, but it's going to take a while:

There is a portal from Gorgrond to the Timeless Isle, at coordinates 74 24.5. You'll need either Draenor Pathfinding or the Aviana's Feather toy from the Garrison inn quest. From there you can take a flight master's mount to Honeydew Village, or alternatively ride all the way over there. Note that I don't know how much exploration experience you'll get from riding over there, so this might not be a viable option.

Below is a video on how to get to the island:

---

There is also a somewhat glitchier way that I don't know to reliably trigger in Draenor, but if your character ever gets lost between servers or dies in a way that the game doesn't know where to put your corpse, your corpse and ghost usually end up at the Crossroads graveyard in Nortern Barrens. As I said, I don't know how to trigger this in Draenor, so I don't condone or recommend this method.

Comment: Interesting way to get off that island, but unfortunately both of your options require another character of at least lvl 100. Pathfinding includes lvl 100 dailies (and lore master of draenor, which can't be completed at lvl 90 either) and the toy quest requires you to do the Skyreach dungeon on heroic.

Comment: @dly the OP specified he didn't want other PLAYERS helping him. He didn't say anything about this being his first character or his only character. I personally would find it weird that an entirely new player would want his very first character to stay EXP locked until they experienced all raids at a level, or even know about EXP lock to begin with.

Comment: Probably, but I still thought it's worth mentioning.